# Why wordpress site asking for language translation?

Tags: php, wordpress, localization

I have developed a website royalartandmarble.com using wordpress. The site is in English but in clients mobile device it is asking for translation of the page. I cannot have the client device for testing. What can be the possible reason or configuration?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If he's in another country the browser recognizes it and automatically asks if you want to translate the page. I don't think it has anything to do with how you set up your site...

Comment: If you want your site in number of languages then only you should think about translation, there are various plugins available to make your job easy, may be known to you well.

Comment: As @dingo_d pointed out, it must be the browser asking the translation prompt due to user's location in non-eng country or non-eng OS or Language selected in the system as default. I tested your site at my browser, it worked fine without any prompt for translation.

Comment: Have you used Lorem Ipsum text on the page anywhere? Chrome sometimes offers to translate it.

Comment: @dingo_d i am not sure if it is only from the clients mobile issue then its not my concern. But I want to know if I can change any settings so that I can stop it asking by google translator.

Comment: I haven't heard of stopping it, since it's the browser who asks that question. Try searching the browsers support if there is a way to do that. It's a minor issue tho, all the user has to do is to say: I don't want to translate the content and the notification goes away...